# Recursively find the parent of a node in tree

Tags: swift, algorithm, tree, binary-search-tree

I have implemented a (non-binary) tree data structure like this:

```
class Node {
    var id: String
    var children: [Node] = []
}
```

To find a node with a given id as well as its parent, I have the following function:

```
extension Node {
    func searchNodeAndParent(_ id: String, parentNode: Node) -> (Node?, Node?) {
        if id == self.id {
            return (self, nil)
        }
        for child in children {
            if let found = child.searchNodeAndParent(id, parentNode: self).0 {
                return (found, parentNode)
            }
        }
        return (nil, nil)
    }
}
```

However, I cannot seem to find the correct parent with `rootNode.searchNodeAndParent(id, parentNode: nil)`. I suspect that `self` might not be the correct parent to use as the parameter, but do not know how I can fix it.

Comment: what is `searchNodeAndParent`? is it a typo and supposed to be `searchAndParent`?

Comment: In your `for` loop, you should check if the any of the children is the node you are looking for directly, instead of recursively calling the function again. If you find, then you are done, otherwise, repeat the `for` only calling the function again for every child, without any `if`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You keep returning the `parentNode` of the current node, instead of the one that one of the recursive functions may have found.

What you'd want to do is:

- check if this node the one you want
- for each child, start the recursion, passing `self` as the parent. If the recursion returns a non-nil result of `(node, parent)`, return the tuple as-is.

Also, your return type should probably be: `(Node, Node?)?` - i.e. either the entire tuple is `nil` indicating a Not Found result, or if the tuple exists a parent could still be `nil` in the case of the root.

```
extension Node {
  func searchNodeAndParent(_ id: String, parentNode: Node?) -> (Node, Node?)? {
     if id == self.id {
        return (self, parentNode) // create the found result here
     }
     for child in children {
        if let found = child.searchNodeAndParent(id, parentNode: self) {
           return found // return what was found as-is
        }
     }
     return nil // nothing was found, the entire result is nil
  }
}
```

Unrelated, but you might want to hide this method that takes in the `parentNode` parameter from the API surface (e.g. make it `private`), and give users a more convenient function that only takes the `id` as the parameter:

```
extension Node {
  func searchNodeAndParent(_ id: String) -> (Node, Node?)? {
     searchNodeAndParent(id, parentNode: nil)
  }
    
  private func searchNodeAndParent(_ id: String, parentNode: Node?) -> (Node, Node?)? {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I had implemented separate search node and search parent functions, but did not figure out how to do it together. Using `(Node, Node?)?` made me realize what I was doing wrong. I changed it to `parentNode: Node? = nil`.